# Fingerprint Sensor AS608 Not Detected on Wemos D1 R1 (ESP8266)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266, fingerprinting

I'm encountering an issue where my AS608 fingerprint sensor works flawlessly when connected to an
Arduino Uno but isn't being detected when connected to a Wemos D1 R1 board (ESP8266). The sensor doesn't respond, and I'm unable to enroll fingerprints or perform any operations.

attempting to resolve the issue with my AS608 fingerprint sensor not being detected on a Wemos D1 R1 board (ESP8266):

-I tried adjusting the voltage to 5V to match the sensor's requirements.

- I experimented with different pins on the Wemos D1 R1 board, ensuring compatibility with the sensor.
- I swapped out USB cables to eliminate the possibility of a faulty connection.
  Wiring Verification: I meticulously verified the wiring setup to confirm it aligns with the sensor's specifications.

Despite these efforts, the sensor continues to remain undetected on the Wemos D1 R1 board.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
 
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(D6, D5); 

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

uint8_t id;

void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("\n\nAdafruit Fingerprint sensor enrollment");

  Serial.print("sensor password =");
  finger.begin(57600);
  Serial.println(finger.verifyPassword());
  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
    while (1) { delay(1); }
  }
}

uint8_t readnumber(void) {
  uint8_t num = 0;
  
  while (num == 0) {
    while (! Serial.available());
    num = Serial.parseInt();
  }
  return num;
}

void loop()                    
{
  Serial.println("Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
  Serial.println("Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger as...");
  id = readnumber();
  if (id == 0) {// ID #0 not allowed, try again!
     return;
  }
  Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
  Serial.println(id);
  
  while (!  getFingerprintEnroll() );
}

uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll() {

  int p = -1;
  Serial.print("Waiting for valid finger to enroll as #"); Serial.println(id);
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz(1);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }
  
  Serial.println("Remove finger");
  delay(2000);
  p = 0;
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER) {
    p = finger.getImage();
  }
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = -1;
  Serial.println("Place same finger again");
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }


  p = finger.image2Tz(2);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }
  
  // OK converted!
  Serial.print("Creating model for #");  Serial.println(id);
  
  p = finger.createModel();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Prints matched!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH) {
    Serial.println("Fingerprints did not match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   
  
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = finger.storeModel(id);
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
   // Serial.println("Stored!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION) {
    Serial.println("Could not store in that location");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR) {
    Serial.println("Error writing to flash");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }  
  
     return p; 
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware question than a programming question.

Comment: how ? could you explain more please

Comment: Debugging 101: When things are not working, you need to 1)provide your wiring diagram; 2) provide your code so we know what have you tried. Otherwise, it simply not answerable... If your Uno can't even detected the present of the sensor, you probably didn't wire the UART interface correctly or using the wrong UART port...